# how to show and hide two div in Angular modal with one variable

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-modal

I'm using Angular 5 and I want to show and hide a div with variable

I've made this in HTML file :

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!passwordOk">
  <input id="idInputPwd" type="password" [(ngModel)]="password"/>
  <button id="idLoginBtnSubmit" (click)="checkPassword()"/>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="passwordOk">
  <label>Access OK</label>
</ng-container>
```

In my component i've this simple method :

```
passwordStored = "test";
password = "";
passwordOk = false;

public checkPassword() {
        if(this.password === this.passwordStored){
            this.passworkOk = true;
        } else {
            this.passworkOk = false;
        }
  }
```

When I click on the button and the password is OK, the second div isn't showed and the first isn't hide

I think the binding doesnt work correctly in modal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a mistype in your function, should be `this.passwordOk` not `this.passworkOk`

```
public checkPassword() {
  if(this.password === this.passwordStored){
    //this.passworkOk = true;
    this.passwordOk = true;
  } else {
    //this.passworkOk = false;
    this.passwordOk = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I like to use *ngIf.. ; else .. syntax on like these situations;

```
<ng-container *ngIf="passwordOk; else passwordNotOk">
  <label>Access OK</label>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #passwordNotOk>
  <input id="idInputPwd" type="password" [(ngModel)]="password"/>
  <button id="idLoginBtnSubmit" (click)="checkPassword()"/>
</ng-template>
```

It is more user friendly and readable I think that using the ngIf like above.